# Using scrapy selector with conditions

Tags: python, scrapy, css-selectors, web-crawler

I am using "scrapy" to scrape a few articles, like these ones: https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/championships-arent-won-on-paper-but-what-if-they-were/
I am using the following code in my spider:

```
    def parse_article(self, response):
       il = ItemLoader(item=Scrapping538Item(), response=response)
       il.add_css('article_text', '.entry-content *::text')
```

...which works. But I'd like to make this CSS-selector a little bit more sophisticated.
Right now, I am extracting every text passage. But looking at the article, there are tables and visualizations in there, which include text, too. The HTML structure looks like this:

```
<div class="entry-content single-post-content">
    <p>text I want</p>
    <p>text I want</p>
    <p>text I want</p>
    <section class="viz">
        <header class="viz">
            <h5 class="title">TITLE-text</h5>
            <p class="subtitle">SUB-TITLE-text</p>
        </header>
        <table class="viz full"">TABLE DATA</table>
    </section>
    <p>text I want</p>
    <p>text I want</p>
</div>
```

With the code snipped above, I get something like:

> text I want
>   text I want
>   text I want
>   TITLE-text   <<<< (text I don't want)
>   SUB-TITLE-text  <<<<  (text I don't want)
>   TABLE DATA  <<<<  (text I don't want)
>   text I want
>   text I want

My questions:

- How can I modify the `add_css()`function in a way such that it
  takes all text except texts from the table?
- Would it be easier with the function `add_xpath`?
- In general, what would be the best practise for this? (extract text
  under conditions)

Feedback would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `>` in your CSS expression to [limit it to children (direct descendants)](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XPath/CSS_Equivalents#Child_Equivalent).

```css
.entry-content > *::text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get output that you want with XPath and `ancestor` axis:

```
'//*[contains(@class, "entry-content")]//text()[not(ancestor::*[@class="viz"])]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I miss something crucial, the following xpath should work:

```
import scrapy
import w3lib

raw = response.xpath(
    '//div[contains(@class, "entry-content") '
    'and contains(@class, "single-post-content")]/p'
).extract()
```

This omits the table content and only yields the text in paragraphs and links as a list. But there's a catch! Since we didn't use `/text()`, all `<p>` and `<a>` tags are still there. Let's remove them:

```
cleaned = [w3lib.html.remove_tags(block) for block in raw]
```